# Server can't find srv.example.net: SERVFAIL

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так, и как исправить ошибку.

nslookup srv

```
Server:     127.0.0.1Address:    127.0.0.1#53** server can't find srv.example.net: SERVFAIL
```

nano /var/lib/bind/reverse.db

```
TTL 86400      ;       1 dayexample.net.    IN      SOA     srv01.example.net.      admin.example.net.        (        20110103        ; Serial        10800           ; Refresh        3600            ; Retry        604800          ; Expire        86400)          ; Minimum TTLIN              NS      srv01.example.net.IN              A       192.168.0.10localhost       IN      A       127.0.0.1srv01           IN      A       192.168.0.10
```

nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain example.netsearch example.netsrv.example.net 127.0.0.1nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Так-же:

```
user@wowza-srv:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        waiting for pid 21602 to die                                                                         [ OK ] * Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [ OK ] user@wowza-srv:~$ tail /var/log/syslogJul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: dns_master_load: /var/lib/bind/reverse.db:1: unexpected end of inputJul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file /var/lib/bind/reverse.db failed: unexpected end of inputJul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone example.net/IN: has no NS recordsJul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: zone example.net/IN: not loaded due to errors.Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: all zones loadedJul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить знак `$` перед директивой `TTL`.

```
$TTL 86400      ;       1 day
```

На это нам намекает и сообщение в `syslog`:

```
Jul  2 22:23:06 wowza-srv named[21679]: dns_master_load: /var/lib/bind/reverse.db:1: unexpected end of input
```

Что следует читать как: "синтаксическая ошибка в первой строке, парсер дальше не пойдет".